# Can read my class inside the mouse click event but can't modify it, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, binding

I have some problem that i can only update my gui inside my Mainwindow() method. And cant really figure out why it does not work inside a event to change the gui. Im using bindings and a viewmodel class as well.

So it seems like my bindings stop to work when i go outside my mainwindow?

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public ObservableCollection<ChessPiece> ItemX { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
       ItemX = new ObservableCollection<Chess>();

       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = ItemX ;
       ItemX.Add(new Chess() { PosX = 0, PosY = 0, Type_ = Piece.Farmer, Player_ = PiecePlayer.Black });
       ItemX.Add(new Chess() { PosX = 0, PosY = 1, Type_ = Piece.Farmer, Player_ = Player.Black });


  ItemX.ElementAt(1).PosX = 5; //This works perfect, my GUI changes! 
}      

 public void ChessBoardClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       ItemX.ElementAt(0).PosX = 3; //Wont work, but the values inside ItemX changes. 


    }
```

Comment: You said *my GUI changes*, but where is the GUI? What it is bound to? Does the `Chess` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your GUI doesn't *change* so much as *start off right*... you don't have a `MainWindow` method, you have a `MainWindow` constructor. The UI will only finish updating after that constructor has completed, by which time `PosX` will be 5 already.

To get your UI to react to property changes, your `Chess` class will need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), so that an event will be fired when you change the `PosX` property.

As a side note, it would be more idiomatic to use the collection's indexer than the `ElementAt` method, e.g.

```
ItemX[0].PosX = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brilliant answer! I had actually added INotiftyProbertyChange in my chess class did assume it was propertychange that was updating my ui the whole time, not the constructor so I thought it was working. Did check it again now and notice I hade some misspelling, it works now! So thanks again! :) And also thanks for correcting my false assumption and as well the ItemX[0]!